# BroadcastReceiver receives when service is started each time

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service, android-audiomanager

I have a dynamically registered `BroadcastReceiver` on a `Service`. It gets `AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_CHANGED_ACTION` as `IntentFilter`. Every time I start the service I get the log message in `onReceive()` method. It works normally after that. I do not want it to receive once when service is started each time. Could you please tell me what I am missing here?

```
    receiver=new BroadcastReceiver(){
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
             Log.d("zil", "degisti");

        }
    };
    IntentFilter filter=new IntentFilter(
                    AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_CHANGED_ACTION);
    registerReceiver(receiver,filter);
```

Comment: retagged with android-specific tag `android-service`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The intent you are interested in, `AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_CHANGED_ACTION`, is "sticky". That means that the system always keeps the last broadcast sent and whenever a `BroadcastReceiver` is registered that is interested in that Intent, it receives it right away. This is a very useful feature but sometimes it isn't what you want ;-)

I assume that you are only interested in actual "change" events. In this case you need to ignore the "current" event and listen only for any events that happen in the future. Lucky for you, there is a solution:

In 'onReceive()' do the following:

```
if (isInitialStickyBroadcast()) {
    // Ignore this one as we aren't interested in the current state
} else {
    Log.d("zil", "degisti");
    // Do whatever you want to do with the event here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
unregisterReceiver(receiver);
```

this probably wont work because you created an Anonymous inner class implementation of BroadcastReciever. instead create a nested/private class that extends BroacastReceiver in the activity where you want your service started. Then dynamically register and unregister your receivers in the Activity lifecycle callbacks

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however unregister(receiver) works, I have put it in onDestroy method of the service. When I call stopService from activity receiver unregisters.